# Suitable melee or ranged weapons for weak mages?

Tags: magic, warfare, weapons, tactics

My Pyromancers are considered the weakest mages of the kingdom,This guys can only ignite things in fire with small but powerful non-lethal taser-like sparks using their minds,this skill is limited by range of sight,magicka is not required for piromancy,Pyros can effectively spam enemy infantry with blinding sparks and deliver electrical pain to the frontlines ally or enemy alike,The king does not want to waste their talent.

I want to use this guys as infantry like swordsmen or archers enhancing their magic with flammable substances at medium range combat.

Could this humble mages become effective elite troops with the right weapons and war tactics?

Comment: Give them a Hwacha to compliment the flames with some fireworks?   Very hard to answer this as it lacks acceptance criteria beyond idea generation

Comment: No gunpowder exist in my world.

Comment: Could it? Who can say? Closing as Primarily Opinion Based.

Comment: Best weapon is completely dependent upon context. Not just of the wielder but of the expected engagement with the enemy, cost, place of manufacture, political climate, logistical concerns, etc..... Note how modern militaries have more than one weapon.

Comment: @sphennings *SUITABLE* ^^

Comment: Best is a strict subset of suitable. All the same problems that exist with best exist with suitable with the addition of the questions being much broader.

Comment: Yes.  Arm them with slings,  and their average effective lethal range would be 200 meters without magic. By magically enhancing their shot,  they can do all sorts of nastiness beyond what the basic slinger can do.  Slings were a party of every army from at least the bronze age until the late 19th century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If range is line-of-site, your infantry men could be parked at high elevation to taser the enemy from far beyond archer range. Defensively, they could be stationed on high walls and towers

Catapults could lob jars of oil, that these units could light after delivery from any range.

As infantry, these people could break shield walls (because they can taser the person holding the shield) and break lines of pike men (because their power reaches past the spear). In these formations, it's vital that every soldier maintain their place (which they can't do if zapped to the ground and writhing). This would make them an alternative to cavalry (whose job is the same thing, but they expose themselves to personal injury to do it). These could also be used to open a hole in a pike wall to allow cavalry through to rush archers or demolish dismounted infantry.

This kind of unit could also be useful as anti-armor. As Game of Thrones well showed, a knight in full metal armor is nearly untouchable by anything except a set pike, lance or javelin. Your pyromancer could just zap the armored unit and he is down, where weaker infantry could pull off the armor or drown him/her in muck.

This unit could also be excellent anti-cavalry, either zapping the mount or zapping the knight off his horse. Since cavalry move quickly, they are very challenging for anyone else to engage, but your pyromancers could dismount them accurately with a glance.

You could also use your pyromancers as anti-seige. They could zap enemy soldiers on ladders, keeping them stuck and blocking their comrades from ascending. They could zap whatever is pulling towers (provided it is in line of sight), zap catapult/trebuchet crews, light enemy oil while it is still in the trebuchet (causing explosions in the enemy ranks).